# Interact With Azure AKS Cluster Master Node REST API

Tags: azure, kubernetes

My requirement here is very simple, I provisioned an AKS cluster and I would like to deploy services to this cluster dynamically through the master NODE's REST API uses a bearer token generated with a service principles credentials.

I cannot seem to find any example of this. All the tutorials end at the kubectl level which is useless for what I need.

This in theory should be doable, any help is welcomed.

NOTE: The application I would like to provision from is running python and also is running outside of the cluster.

Service Principal:

```
{
  "appId": "0c6f1e71-b6fe-4187-8de6-3f84a419c0db",
  "displayName": "deployer",
  "name": "http://deployer",
  "password": "xxxxxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "tenant": "xxxxxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

Service Account:

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: alice-cluster-admin
  namespace: default
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["*"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: alice-cluster-admin
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: User
  name: 2210df5a-94d5-489f-9c6f-0d9d71bef61a
```

Python Request For Token:

```
import requests 

print( 
requests.get( 
 url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/sometenantname.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token", 
data={ 
'grant_type':'client_credentials', 
'client_id':'2210df5a-94d5-489f-9c6f-0d9d71bef61a', 
'client_secret':'xxxxxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx', 
'resource':'https://graph.microsoft.com' 
} 
).content 
)
```

The returned token produces a 401 error on the Kube API when requests are made

```
{
    "kind": "Status",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {},
    "status": "Failure",
    "message": "Unauthorized",
    "reason": "Unauthorized",
    "code": 401
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To have the bearer token of a serviceaccount, one way is to generate the kube config file.

You can use the [view_serviceaccount_kubeconfig](https://github.com/superbrothers/kubectl-view-serviceaccount-kubeconfig-plugin) plugin for kubectl (using [krew](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/krew) for instance)

To generate the kube config file of service account **for** in **bar** namespace:

```
> kubectl view_serviceaccount_kubeconfig --namespace bar foo
```

Then you can get the token from the `token` field from the output of the command.

Comment: You see this is my problem, it's all relating to the kubectl command, how can I obtain the bearer through either python or a REST API?

Answer (score 0):

The master nodes of AKS is managed by Microsoft and you can not access them to deploy anything there. You can only use Kubernetes API exposed by those master nodes to deploy workloads(pods etc) into the worker nodes.

You should use azure AD(which provides the bearer token) not azure service principles for interacting with AKS cluster's Kubernetes API Server using kubectl. Check the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-ad-rbac?toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Faks%2FTOC.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json).

After you do this use any kubectl command `kubectl get pods --v=10 | grep -i bearer` which would give you the bearer token. Now you can call Kubernetes REST APIs using the same token.

Comment: The problem is I don't want to use the kubectl command, I'm running a python app that manages my orchestration through triggers in the app. So I want to do it directly against that master's API (" Kubernetes API exposed by those master nodes"), so in essence, take the SP credentials, obtain oauth2 token, send command + oauth token to the kubernetes API and deploy or list things.

Comment: that python app is running inside the kubernetes cluster or outside?

Comment: Failed to mention that, it's running outside, if it was running inside then a plain service account would have done the trick :)

Comment: yes you are right on that...now I am not sure if its achievable from outside...have you tried to call azure ad api(equivalent of az aks get-credentials) from the python app to get a token and use that to call Kubernetes API...all that matters is what groups that JWT token has.

Comment: I added the requests to my original answer if you want to have a look, I suspect that it might have something to do with how I'm requesting the token or with the service account bindings

Comment: Found a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution that will allow authentication while using RBAC capabilities: [RBAC Tokens](https://api.spotinst.com/container-management/kubernetes/kubernetes-tutorials/create-a-kubernetes-bearer-token/)

This solution allows you to create a token and use that token through the cluster's RESTful API.